# Open an external URL from a struts sub-menu in menu-config.xml

Tags: url, struts, external

I am trying to open an external link from my menu-config.xml submenu..Is this possible to do ?
It is not working for me

```
<Menu name="MainMenu" title="MainMenu" description="MainMenu">

  <Item name="Google" title="Google" description="Google" link="http://www.google.com" ></Item>
  <Item name="Google" title="Google" description="Google" link="http://www.google.com" ></Item>

</Menu>
```

I tried using location and like this 
menu name="google" link="javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com/');"

Thanks

Comment: Add a link to the plugin you are using. Which Struts version?

Comment: I am using 1.2..not sure which plugin you are referring to ?

Comment: `menu-config.xml` - where this configuration file is coming from?